# Deploy mariaDB and nextcloud via Docker with a mariaDB error message

Tags: docker, mariadb, nextcloud

I have a question about nextcoud, mariaDB and Docker.

Initial situation:
I have a Synology NAS and would like to install mariaDB and nextcloud via Docker.

I found a tutorial here: https://mariushosting.com/synology-how-to-install-nextcloud-using-docker/

As in the tutorial I also use portainer.

Here is my configuration in compose file format:

```
version: '2.9'

services:
  
  mariadb:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: mariadb
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloudatabasename
      - MYSQL_USER=nextclouduser

  nextcloud:
    container_name: nextcloud
    ports:
      - 40010:80
    links:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      - PUID=1024
      - PGID=100
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    volumes:
      - /volume1/docker/nextcloudStable/html:/var/www/html
      - /volume1/docker/nextcloudStable/custom_apps:/var/www/html/custom_apps
      - /volume1/docker/nextcloudStable/config:/var/www/html/config
      - /volume1/docker/nextcloudStable/data:/var/www/html/data
      - /volume1/docker/nextcloudStable/themes:/var/www/html/themes/
    image: nextcloud
    restart: always

volumes:
  mariadb: # nextcloud
```

After deployment I also get the installation page of nextcloud under IP of NAS: http://192.168.1.10:40010/

I entered mariadb as host and get the following error message:

```
Error while trying to create admin user: 
Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in driver: 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'nextclouduser'@'172.17.0.7' (using password: YES)
```

Could someone please explain me why the error occurs and how I can fix it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What password did you use?

Comment: I tried both mysqlpassword and rootpassword. But in my opinion it should be mysqlpassword. both dosen´t worked.

Comment: Try `docker-compose down -v` and then `docker-compose up -d` and see if one of the passwords work, instead of manual password reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I set up my container with Portainer. Here I logged in the mariaDB container and set the PW manually.

```
mysql -u root -p
SET PASSWORD FOR 'nextclouduser'@'%' = PASSWORD('X123');
```

I also tried the deployment with a docker-compose.yml file and the `docker-compose up -d` command. No manual PW setting was necessary.

Comment: "Can anyone explain this behavior?"—the answer section isn't for more questions. Either edit your original question or ask a new one, please. See [ask] and [answer].

Answer (score 1):

below works for me just do it as a stack in portainer

```
version : '3.8'

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:
  
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW --innodb-file-per-table=1 --skip-innodb-read-only-compressed

    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=passt
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      
      
  cloud:
      image: nextcloud
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 8888:80
      links:
        - db
      volumes:
        - nextcloud:/var/www/html
      environment:

      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
```